# Assigning struct data in struct array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Header file book_info struct

```
struct book_info {
         char title[50];
         char author[40];
         unsigned int year_published;
     };

typedef book_info;
book_info books[20];

void init_heap() {
    head = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            books[i].year_published = i+1;
        }
    books[20].year_published = 10000;
}
```

Trying to make an array of book_info structs, and then assign the year published of each struct to a number when initializing. Not sure exactly what the problem is?

Comment: What do you mean by `typedef book_info;`??

Comment: `books[20].year_published` accesses out of bounds. The valid indices are `0` through `19`.

Comment: Your question should include exactly what problem you are having (including the exact text of any compiler error/warning messages)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
typedef book_info;
```

you need

```
typedef struct book_info book_info;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem by two ways.

1.`typedef struct book_info book_info;`

2.

```
struct book_info{
//...
    }books[20];
```